# How do I include a PHP file which is in the current theme path?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a PHP file in my current theme directory and trying to include it.

I tried with this script:

```
include(get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/my-own-php-file.php');
```

But I couldn't include it with this error:

> "include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0"

If I can't edit my php.ini file, how can I include my own file in my theme directory?

Comment: Wordpress has a [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function.   You can `get_template_part( 'myfile' );`  and it'll try to include `myfile.php` from your template directory. But your problem here is that `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` returns an URL, which you can do with include but it's considered risky to just run arbitrary code from some url (which is why it's blocked by default on your server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
include get_template_directory().'my-own-php-file.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

also can be used 
include get_template_directory('my-own-php-file.php');